# htaaccess Wordpress strip old Blogger comments urls and redir to main WP page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm getting a lot of 404 caused by old Blogger comments url looking like

domain.com/feeds/1956758672484944774/comments/default
domain.com/feeds/4545454545484944774/comments/default

I would like to strip all the strange numbers (/feeds/4545454545484944774/comments/default) and redir users just to my main page http://domain.com

Could somebody share a htaaccess rule for it

Thanks
Sellio

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as **very first rule** in your WP `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^feeds/\d+/ / [L,NC,R=301]
```